# starting slf4j bundle doesn't start on felix

Tags: java, osgi, bundle, slf4j

I have `felix-framework-5.0.1` and I'm trying to start `slf4j-api-1.6.0.jar` bundle into felix isgi container.

1. in felix console I'm typing `install file:bundle/slf4j-api-1.6.0.jar`
2. I'm getting a message `Bundle ID: 42`
3. then I'm trying to start the bundle `start 42`
4. I'm getting the message

`org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve slf4j.api [42](R 42.0): missing requirement [slf4j.api [42](R 42.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.p
ackage=org.slf4j.impl)(version>=1.5.5)) Unresolved requirements: [[slf4j.api [42](R 42.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.slf4j.impl)(version>=
1.5.5))]
g!`

Can any body help me? how can I start `slf4j` bundle into felix?

Answer (score 1):

slf4j-api needs *org.slf4j.impl* package. This package is included into every slf4j implementations like slf4j-simple, slf4j-logback, etc.

The implementation bundles need *org.slf4j* package that comes from the API artifact. There is a cross-reference. This can work only due to the reason that implementations are [fragment bundles](http://wiki.osgi.org/wiki/Fragment) of the API. When the implementation is installed together with the API, they will have a common classloader and they will be resolved together. Both of their requirements will be satisfied.

In short: You must choose one of the implementations and install that as well. E.g.: [slf4j-simple](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.slf4j%22%20AND%20a%3A%22slf4j-simple%22).

You should use the same version of API and implementation to satisfy their "cross requirement".

Answer (score 0):

Your library contains the following 3 packages ([link](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/1.6.0)):

1. `org.slf4j`
2. `org.slf4j.helpers`
3. `org.slf4j.spi`

but you have to have an additional library that will contain `org.slf4j.impl` package.

Also, from manifest file you can see what packages are exported (`Export-Package`) (they are visible by other bundles) and what packages are imported (`Import-Package`) (they have to be accessible for the given bundle). Sometimes the given package have to be from bundle with the correct version.

---

If you cannot find correct bundle maybe this [page](http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/) will help you.

Comment: http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/bundle/version/detail?name=com.springsource.slf4j.api&version=1.5.11&searchType=bundlesByName&searchQuery=slf4j
Here I can download the bundle, but it doesn't start as well.
So I've looked at the source code of this bundle. and impl package is excluded from there.

Comment: you should addicionally download one of the following library: http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/search?query=org.slf4j.impl Each of them export the `org.slf4j.impl` package.